# CakePHP - Paginating an Array

Tags: cakephp

Cake handles pagination of a model with a simple $this->paginate(), but what should I use if I want to paginate a array of values?

The Scenario is like this:

```
$this->set('sitepages', $this->paginate());
```

This code in my index() returns an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Sitepage] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [name] => Home
                    [urlslug] => home
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [page_title] => Welcome to KIAMS, Pune
                    [order] => 1
                )   
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Sitepage] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 26
                    [name] => About Us
                    [urlslug] => aboutus
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [page_title] => 
                    [order] => 2
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Sitepage] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 27
                    [name] => Overview of KIAMS
                    [urlslug] => aboutus/overview
                    [parent_id] => 26
                    [page_title] => 
                    [order] => 2
                )
        )
```

I retrieved the same data using $this->Sitepage->find('all') and then performed some manipulations as required and form a array which is very similar to the above one, but the ordering gets changed. I want to paginate this new array and pass it to the view. I tried

```
$this->set('sitepages',$this->paginate($newarray))
```

But the data is not getting paginated. Can some one please help with paginating the $newarray in CakePHP?

Answer (score 2):

To paginate in CakePHP you need to pass select conditions to the paginate() call.

Other data manipulation should be done in afterFind(), in your model file.

If you don't need these changes to be done in every single retrieval, you might as well consider creating a new model file pointing to the very same table as the current one, and adding an afterFind() method to that new file.

Comment: Creating a model in my opinion would be a overkill.. Surely there must be some simple way to paginate an array of data...

Comment: Does the PaginatorHelper assist in any way?  It looks like you can use it to paginate data from within the view.  It may do what you need.  http://book.cakephp.org/view/166/Pagination-in-Views

Comment: @Ashok When you use a framework things that should be easy in others not necessarily are in this one. They give you some great features, but when you need some extra customization you'll probably get into ad-hoc solutions in all possible frameworks, not just CakePHP.

Comment: @Travis, Paginator Helper will help in displaying the paginated data received from the controller... We can't use the helper to paginate data from within the view. All paginations happen in the Controller and then come to view...

Comment: Agreed. I thought there would be some way, but I guess not since the Paginator definitely takes in a Model only. Thanks to everyone for your time..

Comment: +1 for giving me a new idea of usein multiple models for same table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using cakephp version 1.3 and it seems this one is working:

at controller:

```
$result = $this->Paginate('Event');
$results = $this->Task->humanizeEvent($result);

$this->set('events', $results);
```

and it seems to display as a normal paginated array, at the view (setup your pagination in view as normal).

The `humanizeEvent` function just edits a field on the results array, to make it a sentence based on other fields inside the array, and it seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've just dealt with this same problem...

I found the only way is to use the `paginate()` function to handle all the logic, rather than passing it a custom array. However, this isn't as bad as it seems:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 2,
    'order' => array(
        'Report.name' => 'asc'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Account.id' => $this->foo()
    ),
);
$reports = $this->paginate();
```

In this example, I'm paginating  Reports - but some Reports will not be included, depending on which Account they belong to (Account has some relationship with Report, hasmany, etc.).

By writing `$paginate` inside your action, you can use a custom callback for the conditions array. So function `foo()` can be written in your controller (or shoved to model) and returns an array of valid Account IDs.

I found I could easily rewrite my custom logic in this function - keeping both me and the Cake paginator happy.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`$this->paginate($newarray)` is the wrong way to paginate. The first parameter cannot be an array. It must be [a model name](http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerpaginate). You may want to study [pagination setup](http://book.cakephp.org/view/165/Controller-Setup) from the manual. This will order alphabetically:

```
var $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 25,
    'order' => array(
        'Sitepage.name' => 'asc'
    )
);
$this->set('sitepages', $this->paginate('Sitepage'));
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question... the problem is not with pagination, but with some tweaked resultset he wants to paginate.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem, I pass an array of conditions to Model->find('all') and the results are as I expect. However, I am unable to paginate with the conditions. Grrrr

Answer (score 0):

I create a component checking the paginator code..

Is not the best thing, but It work for me.....

Controller

```
$slicedArray = array_slice($fullArray,($page - 1) * $this->PaginatorArray->limit ,$this->PaginatorArray->limit)
$this->params['paging'] = $this->PaginatorArray->getParamsPaging('MyModel', $page,    $total,count($slicedArray));
$this->helpers[] = 'Paginator';
```

Component

```
<?php
/* SVN FILE: $Id$ */
/**
 * Pagination Array Component class file.
 * @subpackage    cake.cake.libs.view.helpers
 */
class PaginatorArrayComponent {

    var $limit = 40;
    var $step = 1;

    function startup( & $controller){
        $this->controller = & $controller;
    }

    function getParamsPaging($model, $page, $total, $current){
        $pageCount = ceil($total / $this->limit);
        $prevPage = '';
        $nextPage = '';

        if($page > 1)
            $prevPage = $page - 1;

        if($page + 1 <= $pageCount)
            $nextPage = $page + 1;

        return array(
            $model => array(
                'page' => $page,
                'current' => $current,
                'count' => $total,
                'prevPage' => $prevPage,
                'nextPage' => $nextPage,
                'pageCount' => $pageCount,
                'defaults' => array(
                    'limit' =>  $this->limit,
                    'step' => $this->step,
                    'order' => array(),
                    'conditions' => array(),

                ),
                'options' => array(
                    'page' => $page,
                    'limit' =>  $this->limit,
                    'order' => array(),
                    'conditions' => array(),

                )
            )
        );
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in find("count") and it returned incorrect count if the query resulted in records for only in group. This has been fixed  [click here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/33a879ff411928429a5b0188a68eecd9632f87e3)