# CakePHP pass a array to paginate() - new model

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Hi I've done a find() and added a new field to some of the results:

```
$approved = $this->ExpenseClaim->find('all', array('conditions'=> array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '3')));
$i = 0;
foreach ($approved as $ap) {
    $approved[$i]['ExpenseClaim']['claimTotal'] = $this->ExpenseClaim->expenseClaimTotal($approved[$i]['ExpenseClaim']['id']);
    $i++;
}
```

I now need to pass this to paginate, however I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828760/cakephp-paginating-an-array) that you cannot do this and that I must create another model to use the afterFind() method only on this one particular find.

So I've created the new Model called `ExpenseClaimTotal` and set the UseTable to

```
public $useTable = 'expense_claims';
```

Then in the new models afterFind() method I did a simple debug:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    debug($results);
    //return $results;
}
```

But when I now try and do a find against this new model in pagesController it fails:

```
$this->loadModel('ExpenseClaimTotal');

$approved = $this->ExpenseClaimTotal->find('all', array('conditions'=> array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '3')));
```

This is the error I get:

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`id`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`user_id`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`claim_status_id`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`created`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`modified`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`approved`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`approved_by`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`declined_by`, `ExpenseClaimTotal`.`date_submitted` FROM `expenses`.`expense_claims` AS `ExpenseClaimTotal` WHERE `ExpenseClaim`.`claim_status_id` = 3
```

There doesnt seem to be much in the docs about using 2 models for one table

Comment: Added code and progress to question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't want to paginate an array

You're already performing a find, it's not sensible to perform a find and *then* paginate the resultant array.

Simply paginate your model data directly and inject your total values in the process. As such - if you put your original "added a new field to some of the results" logic in the model:

```
class ExpenseClaim extends AppModel {

    public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {

        foreach ($results as &$ap) {
            if (isset($ap['ExpenseClaim']['id'])) {
                $ap['ExpenseClaim']['claimTotal'] = $this->expenseClaimTotal($ap['ExpenseClaim']['id']);
            }
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Your controller code becomes simply:

```
public function index() {

    $conditions = array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '3');
    $data = $this->paginate($conditions);

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

And the code is simple and "just works".

### Enhancements

The above is the simplest way to achieve the desired results, but has some disadvantages - namely it will call the total method on pretty much all finds.

Depending on exactly what you're doing you may wish to for example:

### Cache your totals

If appropriate, you can remove problems by simply adding the field "claim_total" to the database, and recalculate whenever it changes. That would mean there is absolutely no extra logic when reading from the expense claim model.

### Use a custom find type

If you don't want to recaculate the total on all finds - you can create a [custom find type](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-custom-find)

```
class ExpenseClaim extends AppModel {

    public $findMethods = array('allWithTotals' =>  true);

    protected function _findAllWithTotals($state, $query, $results = array()) {
        if ($state === 'before') {
            return $query;
        }

        foreach ($results as &$ap) {
            $ap['ExpenseClaim']['claimTotal'] = $this->expenseClaimTotal($ap['ExpenseClaim']['id']);
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

And then [use it in your paginate call](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination):

```
public function index() {
    $this->paginate['findType'] = 'allWithTotals'; # <-

    $conditions = array('ExpenseClaim.claim_status_id' => '3');
    $data = $this->paginate($conditions);

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

In this way, only the index method will trigger the call to add the totals.

Comment: Great, thanks once again for your very in-depth answer. I have a couple of question if you dont mind - 
1. So I now have no need for an additional model. 
2. In the custom find type - what is the before state check for?

Thanks again

Comment: 1) no 2) find methods are called twice, once with the query params (conditions) and once with the results

Comment: That's just a variable-reference. meaning that changes to `$ap` are reflected in `$results`, which permits more concise code in these examples.